# Retrieve extended properties from file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure this code may look a little familiar but I am having trouble getting extended properties of files with this looping file path printer code.

- The object properties are easy to get using `Scripting.FileSystem object`
- But when I try to extract the the extended properties I get the error *Object doesn't support this property or method"*

Do I need to create it's own shell?

The code fails on:

> ```
>    Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 3) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFile, 9)
> ```

*existing code*

```
'objFSO: A Scripting.FileSystem object.
Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, _
ByVal intRow As Integer, ByRef objFSO As Object) As Integer
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

    i = intRow - ROW_FIRST + 1
Set objFolder = objFSO.getfolder(strPath)
On Error Resume Next
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'print Date created
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFile.DateCreated
        'print file name
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 2) = objFile.Name

        'Author------>!!!! HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!!
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 3) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFile, 9) 

       'print file path
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 4) = objFile.Path
        'Insert doc link
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 5).Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        objFile.Path, _
        TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name

        i = i + 1
Next objFile
GetAllFiles = i + ROW_FIRST - 1
End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Shell` for this.

On my system the *Author* attribute is 20.

```
Sub HoldtheDoor()

Dim oShell As Object
Dim oDir As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("c:\temp")

For Each objFile In oDir.Items
   Debug.Print oDir.GetDetailsOf(objFile, 20)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Now I need help working that into existing code.Can I insert this into this function or do I need to make a separate function to call to in the looping process?